# Randomizing Picture Links on a Wordpress Blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On my website, I have a section in my right-side navigation dedicated to "seasonal" projects. I want these to be automated and change automatically. Is there a php function that does this? Currently, I simply do it manually w/ html.

My thoughts are that I can somehow seperate, Winter, Fall, Summer, Spring projects, and then call each folder when the time comes. It would also be have to called on a certain date. If anyone could help or point me towards a useful resource, I'd very much appreciate it.

Website: http://www.merrimentdesign.com

The section on the site I am referring two is titled Top Winter Projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is query for posts based on **Date Range**, define said range for Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter, code below should get you started.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Time_Parameters

There are some examples there, but basically you would do something like this (wordpress example):

> // Create a new filtering function
>   that will add our where clause to the
>   query function filter_where( $where =
>   '' ) {    // posts for March 1 to March
>   15, 2010  $where .= " AND post_date >=
>   '2010-03-01' AND post_date <
>   '2010-03-16'";    return $where; }
>   add_filter( 'posts_where',
>   'filter_where' );
>
> query_posts( $query_string );

IF you posts have a post images you would show said post images, if your  theme does NOT support them then you would need to read through here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: How would I show the post images? My theme does support them.

Comment: Wordpress Codex is your friend: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail